# How do I create buttons dynamically in C# onClick of another button? And then have those buttons also do the same

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, dynamic, onclick

I am trying to make a C# web page that creates buttons dynamically based on what the form submits, but I keep running to dead ends.  The problem is that (apparently?) you can only hook up EventHandlers during the Page_Load, and not inside a button's Click event?

Basically I have some code to create a button:

```
private Button CreateButton(string id, string text) {
    Button b = new Button();
    b.ID = id;
    b.Text = text;
    b.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Button_Command);
    b.CommandArgument = text;
    return b;
}
```

And when these new buttons are clicked, they are supposed to pass command arguments, and create new buttons based on those command arguments

```
void Button_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    //Put code here that creates new buttons based on what's submitted
    DoThis(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

But when I run this code inside a button's Click Event, the EventHandler for the newly created buttons don't get hooked up.

There is only a text input and a GO button the first time you hit the page.  It should create a bunch of new buttons along with their command arguments:

```
protected void bntGo_Click(object sender, e EventArgs){
    DoThis(txtInput.Text);
}

private void DoThis(string arg){
    //Do some logic to create a Dictionary<string, int> object (sortedDict) 
    //based on the arg passed, then for each KeyValuePair in the Dictionary, 
    //add a button to a panel on the page, setting each button's commandarguments 
    //to each string in the dictionary
    int count=1;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in sortedDict) {
        pnlButtonsPanel.Controls.Add(CreateButton("Btn"+count.ToString(), pair.Key));
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish this?  I can't just run the DoThis() function every time the page loads because DoThis() needs to be passed CommandArguments from the button that they clicked, which is not available inside page_load.

What am I doing wrong?  I need a new approach.  I'm thinking myself in circles here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't register a handler, you have to actually submit the form and parse the string equivalent of the command on the server. Hence, RunAt Server. There is no magic connection between the rendered page and the server, that's called Javascript.

Have you followed the design pattern here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventhandler.aspx

```
  <asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="Sort Ascending"
       CommandName="Sort"
       CommandArgument="Ascending"
       OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

...

```
void CommandBtn_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
      {

         switch(e.CommandName)
         {

            case "Sort":

               // Call the method to sort the list.
               Sort_List((String)e.CommandArgument);
               break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need to add eventhandlers in Page_Init or Page_Load is the following:

Every postback to the server causes the page to be reconstructed from scratch (unless it's a completely static page and it's getting cached). This causes all dynamic changes (adding a button, ...) to be lost. Thus when you're clicking on a dynamically created button, and don't recreate the button and all handlers in Page_Init or Page_Load, for all intents and purposes, the button does not exist serverside.

---

### Edit:

If you need to save a list with the details of each button, just use the `ViewState`

```
protected void Page_Init (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do your stuff
    var buttonStuff = ViewState["MySaveButtonStuff"] as List<string>;
    if (buttonStuff != null)
    {
        //create button method(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to base the number of new buttons and what their command arguments are on code that happens onclick.  Maybe there's a way to access which button was pressed and it's command arguments inside of page_load or page_init? :/

Comment: @CharlieK See if this does what you want.